# gridpane.getchildren().add() called from outside the controller class blocks the program

Tags: javafx

I'm making a traditional Japanese board game (which is similar to Go). What I wanna do is to put an image in a square of GridPane(15*15) by calling method in the controller class from outside the class. However, the controller program blocks when carrying out "gomokuBoard.getChildren().add(imageview);" in opponent_put_stone() method. What should I do in order to put a control object from outside the controller program?

Following is what I have already done.
I commented out the line of code and carried out the program. It resulted in success except that opponents' stones didn't appear in the GUI screen.

Here is the part of controller class. The line I mention is the last line of "opponent_put_stone" method.

```java
//this method is called by pushing a button in GridPane. this method works.

@FXML private GridPane gomokuBoard;
    @FXML private Button hint_button;
    @FXML private Label messagefromServer;
    @FXML private static Button[][] put_stone_button;
    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseClick;
    private Image black_stone;
    private Image white_stone;
    private static int mycolor = 1;
    private GomokuGame game;


public void put_mystone(MouseEvent event) {
        int x = GridPane.getRowIndex((Node) event.getSource());
        int y = GridPane.getColumnIndex((Node) event.getSource());
        put_stone_button[x][y].setDisable(true);

        game.gomoku.putStone(x, y, mycolor);
        GomokuGame.go_signal();

        ImageView imageview;
        if(mycolor == 1) {
            imageview = new ImageView(black_stone);
        }
        else {
            imageview = new ImageView(white_stone);
        }
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageview, y, x);
        gomokuBoard.getChildren().add(imageview);
        game.x = x;
        game.y = y;
    }

//this method is called from outside the controller program.
    public void opponent_put_stone(int x, int y) {
        put_stone_button[x][y].setDisable(true);

        game.gomoku.putStone(x, y, 3-mycolor);
        ImageView imageview;
        if(mycolor == 1) {
            imageview = new ImageView(white_stone);
        }
        else {
            imageview = new ImageView(black_stone);
        }
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageview, y, x);
        gomokuBoard.getChildren().add(imageview); //this line blocks program
    }
```

Comment: I solved this problem by using Platform.runLater(). Since GUI can be operated only in application thread, the problem occured.

Comment: Voting for close since it's impossible to reproduce with the code+description provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Platform.runLater(). Since GUI can be operated only in application thread, the problem occured.